# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'arc' of undefined in AngularJS and D3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

I am new to AngularJS and D3. I am building a dashboard using these technologies.
I have included the d3.min.js file in the index file and trying to draw a cirle with it.Here is the code:

```
enter code here 
var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 200)
.attr("height", 200)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(100,100)");

 var arc = d3.svg.arc()
 .innerRadius(50)
 .outerRadius(70)
 .startAngle(0)
 .endAngle(2 * Math.PI);

 svg.append("path")
 .attr("class", "arc")
 .attr("d", arc);
```

but I keep on getting a console message : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'arc'

I also tried to draw a barchart but this time the error reported was:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'linear'

Please help

Comment: What's the version of d3? If it's v 4.x, it should be `d3.arc()`.

Comment: D3.js Version 4.1.0.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In D3 v4.x the syntax has changed from:

```
d3.svg.arc();
```

To:

```
d3.arc();
```

Here's a link to the changes in the new API: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md